# String + Variable + String formatting in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python so please go easy, I'm sure my question has a very simple solution, that seems to be evading me.  I'm trying to write a string to a file in this format:

```
"string1" variable "string2"
```

But it always seems to write "string2" "string1" variable

Here is my code:

```
inF = open("f:\test\Users.txt", 'r')
outF = open("f:\test\commands.txt", 'w')

for line in iter(inF):
    s = "{0} {1} {2}" .format("adduser ",line," password")
    outF.write(s)
inF.close()
outF.close()
```

I have also tried:

```
for line in iter(inF):
    outF.write("adduser " + lines + " password")
```

Output is always:

```
passwordadduser user.name
```

Comment: what are you callin iter on an iterator? Also there is no way you get any of the output you have posted

Comment: He's calling iter on a file. And the output makes sense, it's just not complete.

Comment: @garph0 a file is an iterator already, and the `iter` call is redundant, but not harmful. Anyway, I upvoted this and oppose closing it - it's indeed probably that the output lines mostly look like OP describes; just that the subtlety causing the problem has been missed. And isn't that par for the course? :)

Comment: Oooops (about the iter thing) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read a line from a file, it will always include the newline character. You then concatenate that directly. So in fact what you are seeing is this:

```
adduser line1\n
passwordadduser line2\n
passwordadduser line3\n
```

etc.

To fix this, strip the line when you read it:

```
for line in iter(inF):
    line = line.strip('\n')
    s = "{0} {1} {2}\n" .format("adduser ",line," password")
```

Comment: Don't just strip the newline from the input; you'll need to add one to the output lines as well :)

Comment: Also, @germn answer mentions context managers, which is a good thing.

Comment: All thank you very much for the help, the strip was indeed the issue, I'm a bit green so I did not know that the new line character was being read but I understand this now, I see that using context managers is the correct way to reference the files and will be reading a lot more to understand context management in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If you check, you'll see that the first two lines are like this:

```
adduser user1
 passwordadduser user2
```

You are reading the file line by line: `line` will contain a trailing "\n" so when you write it it goes to a new line, and you are not terminating what *you* write with a newline, so you get `passwordadduser`.
Something like:

`outF.write("{0} {1} {2}\n" .format("adduser ",line.strip()," password"))`

Should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please, use context managers to work with files. You should also handle new line symbols `\n` while reading and writing:

```
in_filename = "f:\\test\\Users.txt"
out_filename = "f:\\test\\commands.txt"

with open(in_filename, 'r') as in_fh, open(out_filename, 'w') as out_fh:
    for in_line in in_fh:
        out_line = "{} {} {}\n" .format("adduser", in_line.strip('\n'), "password")
        out_fh.write(out_line)
```

Users.txt:

```
us1
us2
us3
```

commands.txt:

```
adduser us1 password
adduser us2 password
adduser us3 password
```